# "Bash: pipenv: command not found" problem in flask

Tags: python, pipenv

I am relatively new to programming and I am following a tutorial on how to build a Flask QnA app for a school project in Virtual Studio Code (here is the link of the video for reference: https://youtu.be/z8Ewd7z1WpQ)

At the very start of the video, I tried to type in `pipenv install flask` in the bask terminal, but all I got was:

```
$ pipenv install flask                                                                     
bash: pipenv: command not found
```

Some things to bear in mind:
I've installed the latest version of Python both online and from the Microsoft store just by typing `python` in the terminal

I've also typed `pip install pipenv` which seemed to have worked fine

I've also installed Python through the extensions of Visual Studio Code

Also, other commands like `sudo`... for example also don't seem to be working. The only ones that seem to be working are `python` as well as `pip`

Any solutions or proposals for me to do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### pipenv solution

You are simply missing `pipenv` on your computer. You can follow the [install guide here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv#installation).

### sudo alterntive

The tutorial you followed sounds like it was on a unix (likely Linux or MacOS) system. The [sudo command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) exists there, but does not exist in Windows. The equivalent in windows would be to open an administrator terminal, and run your commands there (without sudo). There are quite a lot of commands that exist in the unix ecosystem that do not exist in Windows. If you run into any more "command not found" issues again, you should do a quick search online to see if it is something that doesnt exist on Windows.

### WSL alternative

Alternatively you could try out something called [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install). This is something microsoft has added to Windows in recent years to allow for developers to "run Linux on Windows". This will likely work for your purposes, but will take longer to setup.

I would personally recommend switching to Linux outright if in the future you are doing all of your development work on WSL. You lose a lot of performance when running programs in WSL.

Good luck on your dev journey!